# Passing value from c# to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want send a dynamic value from C# to JavaScript. When I click my button I want to show my value in an alert message.

Here is my C# code :

```
[HttpPost]
[AjaxOnly]
[Authorize(Roles = "DigitalAdmin, DigitalAgency")]
public async Task<ActionResult> YeniKullanici(KullaniciFormModel model)
{
    var yeniKod = SeyahatSaglikController.YeniKod();
    model.KullaniciAdi = ViewBag.Collection;
    var newKullaniciUserName = model.KullaniciAdi + "_" + yeniKod;

    ViewBag.message = newKullaniciUserName;
    // More code here
}
```

Here is my JavaScript function :

```
$('#KullaniciBtn').click(function () {
    var message = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.message));

    alert (message);
    // More code here
}
```

The message is always be null. I'm already using `ViewBag.Collection` and I get this value correctly but I cannot get `ViewBag.message` in JavaScript?

Comment: Try putting `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.message))` inside quotes.

Comment: you mean '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.message))' like this ?

Comment: Are you dynamically creating your JavaScript server side? Because if not, server side variables are not available client side.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your JavaScript function is inside your view, you should be able to set the JavaScript variable like this:

```
$('#KullaniciBtn').click(function () {
    var message = "@Html.Raw(ViewBag.message)";

    alert (message);
    // More code here
}
```

If your function is not inside your view then you can't access the server side ViewBag variable. In that case, you'll have to put the variable value in an html data attribute or an html hidden input.